# JNDI properties file in Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jndi, websphere-liberty

Can anyone please explain the significance of JNDI properties file in worklight app developement, Also is it mandatory to have one JNDI properties file for the mobile app developed using worklight to work.

thanks
djrecker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNDI properties are not unique to Worklight. There is no requirement to use JNDI, rather it is simply a convenient method to lay out various properties that may be used in various environments (QA, UAT, PROD, ...) where you will find yourself deploying the Worklight Server.

As a Worklight Server has many properties that will be different per the environment (ports, hostnames, etc...), using JNDI properties you could better manage them in a single location (file). By not doing so, you may find yourself creating for example multiple .war files - a .war file per environment instead of 1 .war file for all environments, where the required properties for the environment are taken from a single file (the JNDI properties file).

You can read more about this, here: [Configuring a Worklight project in production by using JNDI environment entries](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_using_JNDI_lookup_to_override_WL_properties.html)